# Android Action Bar Customization without ABS

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Need to design Like Given Image, How can i customize like below given image.Thanks in Advance. I Need to Use Action bar
  [image: image to design]

Comment: Why don't you use your own layout and add it to `ActionBar` ?

Comment: can you suggest some reference for that?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653085/actionbar-with-custom-layout-with-custom-menu-item

Comment: No it didn't helped me thanks! anyways.

Comment: I have one more thing should i need to write seperate onclick for the back.

Comment: Your onlcick will be in the normal way only.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to customize your `ActionBar`,

1.Create your own layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/topbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#4169E1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/Back"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_back" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

2. Add the layout  to your `ActionBar`,

```
 actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
 actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
 actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_items);
```

Hope it helps.