# Cart icon not showing up with counter in action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I have an action bar menu which has a cart icon in the top right near three dots. The icon is coming up properly.

in menu/menu.xml I have called the following:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_cart"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/cart"
    android:orderInCategory="1000"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_cart"/>
```

Now I am trying to add a counter according to the click of an item. For which I added an xml with the following in layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/carticon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cart"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/cart" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cart_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/carticon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/carticon"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cart_round"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="17sp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:text="@null"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And then in my fragment file. I am passing the xml like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart).getActionView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.cart_number);
    tv.setText("12");
}
```

Here I am setting the counter on click of an item:

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            itemsInCart = itemsInCart + 1;
            //cartTV.setText(String.valueOf(itemsInCart));
            Log.e("ACTION BAR","CART" +itemInCart);
        }

    });


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    if (rootView != null) 
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();

        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try 
    {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlist, container, false);
    } 
    catch (InflateException e) 
    {

    }

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Nothing is showing up.. and gives error. When I click one of the item from the list view.

But I get NPE error:

```
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865): java.lang.NullPointerException
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at com.ylg.link.Link_GridActivity$1.onItemClick(Link_GridActivity.java:163)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     03-22 12:23:45.598: E/AndroidRuntime(12865):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Yeah I know so what does this mean? I have initialized the values onCreateOptionsMenu right?

Comment: Seems like you switched the ids here: `RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.cart_number).getActionView();
    cartTV = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.action_cart);`. Shouldn't you be using `R.id.action_cart` for `findItem` and `R.id.cart_number` for `findViewById`?

Comment: What is at line no. 163? BTW Check the `itemsInCart` value by printing in logcat. Try `System.out.println(itemsInCart) or Log.d("key",itemsInCart);`

Comment: @YuvaRaj - Prints 1 and then gives error.

Comment: You're overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu(...) in the fragment right? `Perhaps, you're not calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`? And isn't the method defined as `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) `?

Comment: @Vikram: Yep. I am overriding OnCreateOptionsMenu and Also have setHasOptionMenu(true); in OnCreateView part.  I have update my questions accordingly. Please check if they are correct thanks..

Comment: How are you assigning count number `itemsInCart` to the textView?

Comment: For testing purpose I am just giving static number.

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.cart_number).getActionView();
cartTV = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.action_cart);
```

to

```
RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart).getActionView();
cartTV = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.cart_number);
```

because your `TextView` id is `cart_number`. It's not `action_cart`.

Comment: Do I need to add anything in Menu.xml to connect my XML?

Comment: @TheDevMan you refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653085/actionbar-with-custom-layout-with-custom-menu-item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653085/actionbar-with-custom-layout-with-custom-menu-item) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191843/cart-icon-not-showing-up-with-counter-in-action-bar/29191896#29191896](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191843/cart-icon-not-showing-up-with-counter-in-action-bar/29191896#29191896)

Comment: What is the other link? It directly my question?

Answer (score 0):

But if you use AppCompat, you should set the ActionLayout in code
It will definitely work.

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.action_cart);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.cart_number);
    textView.setText("1");
```